# Check whether browser supports svg#Text feature

Tags: javascript, svg

I am working on project where I am using svg#text feature.

I checked it using following snippet

```
document.implementation.hasFeature(
"http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#BasicStructure", "1.1");
```

And it returned `true`

But when I tried following snippet,

```
document.implementation.hasFeature(
"http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Text", "1.1");
```

I am getting `false`.

On more thing I came across is chrome is returning `true` in every case, why?
for eg.

```
document.implementation.hasFeature(
"http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#BlaBlaXYZ", "1.1");
```

Now this too is returning `true` in `chrome`.

**[EDIT]**
Following example is not working in old firefox browsers

```
 <svg id="main_svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;z-index:1;pointer-events:none;height:512px;width:512px">
    <text id="abc" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10pt">
        <tspan id="xyz" x="510" y="243" text-anchor="end" fill="blue">foo</tspan>
        <tspan id="xyz_sh" x="509" y="242" text-anchor="end" fill="white">another foo</tspan>
    <text>
 <svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hasFeature was deprecated some time ago. To ease the migration of people not to use it it still exists (for a while) but is supposed to [always return true](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/hasFeature) regardless of input arguments.

Chrome, Firefox and Edge always return true.

hasFeature was never granular enough.

- Should a browser return true if they implemented text but not tspan.
- What if they implmented both but not multiple x values?
- What if they did multiple x values but there was some bug that meant you couldn't use it?

Comment: How am I supposed to test the support of `svg#Text` with `tspan` and `textarea`?

Comment: All browsers support tspan. None support SVG 1.1 tiny textArea and none plan to so ever so it's pretty easy, no?

Comment: I have edited the question. Can you check the edit? it is working in latest chrome and firefox browsers.

Comment: How old is old?

Comment: I am trying it on `firefox 40`

Comment: That's an unsupported version and is dangerous to use (as are all old browsers) because they have known security holes. Here's what is supported and updated with security fixes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_version_history#Current_supported_official_releases

Comment: I can't migrate to latest version, some company policies. Can you please tell me what is the least version I need for code to work? security is not an issue, the app is used for internal purpose, it is an standalone app, we are running it in headless browser.

Comment: I've no idea which bug you're encountering or when it was fixed. There is a tool to help you do that though: https://mozilla.github.io/mozregression/